# How to use Flutter Desktop open windows explorer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I want to open the windows explorer application, not open a dialog. for example, the Edge's display in a folder.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `file:` URLs for a directory to [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). For instance:

```
launch('file://C:');
```

Comment: Deprecated! now you should use:
final Uri _url = Uri.parse('file:///C:/');
launchUrl(_url);

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin open_file: [open_file: ^3.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file/example)

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
await OpenFile.open('$dir\\');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But this is what I wanted https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/58471330/158991839-8404dd3c-542d-4708-a122-9266061b491f.png

Comment: that only works with android and ios