# How to open windows explorer in flutter-Windows-application?

Tags: flutter, explorer, flutter-windows

The question is pretty straight forward: I develop a windows application with flutter (shame on me) and I want to open the Windows "file explorer" with a path when a button is pressed.
Another great thing would be to open the windows file-picker and get a callback from that, but the other problem seems to be much easier.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71511905/how-to-use-flutter-desktop-open-windows-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the **[file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)** plugin and call

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
```